# Salvar localizacao nas informações da imagem

Tags: android, google-location-api

Preciso tirar uma foto e salvar na galeria e posteriormente enviar para o banco de dados. Porém, queria saber como salvar as coordenadas junto com as informações da imagem. Lembrando que já consigo pegar minha localização, só não consigo salvar ela nas informações na imagem.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File albumF = getAlbumDir();
    File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
    return imageF;
}
```

No código acima eu estou definindo nome, formato e a pasta.

Comment: No seu banco, você tem as colunas para receber a latitude longitude para cada imagem?! Esse seu banco é externo ou interno?

Comment: Tenho um banco interno que salva o caminho da foto, longitude, e latitude, essa informações envio para o banco externo. Porem teria que selecionar a imagem mostrar em um Imageview e pegar lon e lat referente a essa imagem, mas não consegui . Achei a seguinte forma de pegar essa inf da imagem, mas estou tendo que fixar essas informações ou editando a imagem e colocando a localização.

Comment: ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imgPath);
                latitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
                longitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);

Comment: Cara, qual sua dificuldade? Só com esse código ai não dá pra ver muita coisa, não está muito claro. Cadê a parte que você grava no banco? Tem pouca informação na sua pergunta.